# How do I add Navigation Buttons to SwiftUI app?

Tags: swift, iphone, xcode, swiftui, navigationview

I'm very new to Swift and SwiftUI in Xcode and have been working on an app.

I'm trying to have three buttons at the top of the main screen: HOME, ABOUT, HELP.

They all should bring the user to different views (or screens) when tapped on.

I already have the basis of the app created: the background, image, text, text field, and button (will set up for action at a later time). I'm wondering how I can add these buttons to the top of the app on top of my `ZStack` (which includes a `VStack` and an `HStack`) for the background. Here is my code so far:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var accession: String = ""
  
    var body: some View {
     
        ZStack {
            
            // Background navy blue
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 10/255, green: 77/255, blue: 174/255)).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        


            // Background light blue
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(Color(red: 86/255, green: 118/255, blue: 255/255))
                .frame(height: 200)
                .offset(x: 0, y: -200)
            
            VStack {
                
                
                // Image of Logo
                Logo()
                    .offset(x: 0, y: -98)
                
                // Text for user input
                Text("Please enter the gene accession number below")
                    .font(.title)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .offset(x: -9, y: -10)
                
                // Text field for user input Ω£
                TextField("NG_017013", text: $accession)
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                    .offset(x: 0, y: -8)
                
                // Button
                Button(action: {
                    // ParseXML()
                }) {
                    Text("Find my gene! ")
                        .font(.system(size: 23))
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .bold()
                        .padding(.all, 10)
                        .background(Color(red: 86/255, green: 118/255, blue: 255/255))
                        .cornerRadius(20)
                        .offset(x: 0, y: 20)
                
                }.padding()
            }.padding()
            
            
            
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: You used the `navigationview` tag, but never once used `NavigationView`. You know what you needed, and a quick Google search will give you the answer.

Comment: I think this can be in the direction you are searching: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-add-bar-items-to-a-navigation-view

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the ZStack in a NavigationView.
At the bottom inside the NavigationView add...

```
 .navigationBarItems(  
     leading:  
         HStack {  
             NavigationLink(destination: Text("Home View")) {  
                 Text("Home")  
             }  
             NavigationLink(destination: Text("About View")) {  
                 Text("About")  
             }  
         },  
     trailing:  
         NavigationLink(destination: Text("Help View")) {  
             Text("Help")  
         }  
 )
```

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks so much for the help! It helped me get the buttons on the app! I should have mentioned this but I'm trying to build this for the iPad and when I run the simulator, instead of starting on the home page (in the Zstack) it starts on the page where it says "Help View" as if the HELP button was pressed automatically. And if I press back, instead of going back to the Zstack, it just slides a quarter of the way across the screen. Do you know how I would be able to fix this and have the Zstack content take over the screen when pressing back and being the main page when launched?

Comment: Try adding  
`.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())`